# what is difference between ceiling and roundup server in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is difference between the `Ceiling` and `Round` functions in in SQL Server?

I have some query and I get a totally different value in `Round` and `Ceiling` function.

[image]

Comment: There are a few many articles which will be available on Google!

Comment: Made no effort. Reading the documentation should have been your first step. If that was unclear, searching the internet was the next step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is [here](https://sqlstudies.com/2016/10/05/floor-round-and-ceiling/)

**Round** does a standard rounding.  If value is .5 or over then you get back 1. If it’s less than .5 you get back 0

**Ceiling** returns the integer equal to or higher than the value passed in.

```
SELECT ROUND(235.400,0); 

Answer= 235.000 

SELECT  CAST(ROUND(235.400,0) as int) 

Answer= 235
```

Comment: if i want round function value should be in Integer...so how i get this ??

Answer (score 3):

- Round allows decimal values to round the value.
    It will take next value if decimal value is only greater than or equal to 5.
- Ceiling no need to decimal values.
    It will take the next value of the given number. If decimal value is even less than 5.

Answer (score 3):

`ROUND` let's you round values in a standard way (round up from values 5 or higher, round down otherwise). It also takes number of decimal places you want to round to, so if you want to get an integer, you just pass 0 as number of decimal places. See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

`CEILING` is operation, which return **the smallest integer greater than passed number**, so it rounds up to next integer.

**CONLUSION:**

So basic difference: `CEILING` rounds up, while `ROUND` rounds number in standard way.

Another key difference is that `ROUND` let's you specify number of decimal places you want round to.